hoe to clear Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.chrome/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity} error?
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.chrome/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared ? image error
com.android.chrome/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity
